# Upgrade from MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

We have several servers with MySQL 5.6.51 and several with MySQL 5.7.39. What are the right steps to upgrade to latest MariaDB LTS 10.11? I think we can't go directly to 10.11 or?

```
MySQL 5.6.51 > MariaDB 10.0 > MariaDB LTS 10.11
MySQL 5.7.39 > MariaDB 10.2 > MariaDB LTS 10.11
```

Is this right path?

Comment: I'd recommend to upgrade 5.6.51 till 5.7.39 (which is not problematic) then upgrade both servers by the same way according to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-from-mysql-57-to-mariadb-102/

Comment: ok, thank you. and then upgrade to 10.11 from 10.2 should be also without problems?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading/ does not describe such upgrade. You may try - but you'd carefully test the result. PS. I'd prefer the next way: data backup - uninstall 10.2 - install 10.11 - restore. It is more simple in testing (and more fast, also it allows to test the restoring correctness on another computer, w/o real version replacement), and it allows to revert easily if some problems occures.

Comment: [Monty says can go directly](https://monty-says.blogspot.com/2020/04/upgrading-between-major-mariadb-versions.html). If you have time, take a backup/restore from backup and an in-place upgrade on restored version.